# Azure AppServiceConsoleLogs is entering a new log entry for every new line

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-appservice

Azure AppServiceConsoleLogs is entering a new log entry for every new line

It makes the logs very hard to read and creates a ton of bloat in the logs

How can I get AppServiceConsoleLogs, AppServiceHTTPLogs, AppServiceAuditLogs and AppServicePlatformLogs to make one entry per log and not a new entry for every new line?

You can see below even the lines with the ascii art are a new log for each line

here is the result of

```
AppServiceConsoleLogs
| take 1000
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**I tried [AppServiceConsoleLogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/appserviceconsolelogs) query in my Linux App Service and noticed that it's generating each and every console log separately:**

[image]

**You can filter out the logs according to your requirement:**

**Example:**

*Filtering error logs:*

[image]

**To optimize and get the main app logs, you can go with the `AppServiceAppLogs` query:**

[image]